# Map Swift array with specific format

Tags: arrays, swift

Given an array that contains elements like this:

```
let array = [[a], [b, c], [d, e, f]]
```

Is there an elegant way to convert this array to an array which returns a tuple with the index of the outer array:

```
let result = [(a, 0), (b, 1), (c, 1), (d, 2), (e, 2), (f, 2)]
```

Comment: seems like a job interview's question or a homework...

Comment: @holex I can do this with for loop，but this could be more elegant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
let array = [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
let result = zip(array, array.indices).flatMap { subarray, index in
    subarray.map { ($0, index) }
}
```

`result` is:

```
[("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("c", 1), ("d", 2), ("e", 2), ("f", 2)]
```

I used `zip(array, array.indices)` instead of `array.enumerated()` because you specifically asked for a tuple with the array *index* — `enumerated()` produces tuples with zero-based *integer offsets*. If your source collection is an array, it doesn't make a difference, but other collections (like `ArraySlice`) would behave differently.